# A few MongoDB questions

Tags: mongodb

Sorry if this isn't the place to ask about this, not sure where I can ask.

So I've been using SQL to manage my app and it's fairly easy because I'm using SQLite3 so I don't need anything extra I can just make a connection to die database.db file. I saw something about MongoDB and I want to switch to using mongoDB but I ran into a few problems.
I want to use it with a Heroku application so not having to use a host would be great.

(I have seen MongoDBLite and NeDB, my only problem is that those haven't been updated in 6+ years)

So my questions:
1: Is there no possible way to only have a database file and then just make a connection to that without the need for a host like the Atlas stuff.
2: If there is no possible way to use MongoDB like SQLite3, is there a way to host it 24/7 for free without a chance for it to hang or be slow.
3: If its not possible to have a free host, is the free version any good? I saw it has free 512mb storage and shared CPU and shared RAM. Does the shared CPU and shared RAM mean that if there are too many users that the database can become slow to access or hang or just sometimes not do anything?

Sorry if my questions are a written a bit confusing.

Comment: Please pick one question. Also, most of these questions are opinion-based or requests for off--site resources, which are off-topic. I recommend reading through the [tour], [help] and [ask] pages. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB Community Edition is free, in comparison to Enterprise Edition it has only a few limitations (e.g. LDAP authentication and encryption), you can simply install it on your machine. The MongoDB Community Edition has no restrictions in terms of size, CPU, users, etc.

SQLite3 is a file-based database, similar to MS Access. MongoDB is a Client-Server database. So you need to start the MongoDB service and then you can simply use it. Stand-alone installation takes only a few Minutes.

Comment: Thank you very the answer, it makes more sense now. Is there a way to use MongoDB as a file-based database? NeDB has a few limitations, is there something that can give almost the full package in a file-based database not is there no other way?

Comment: No as said, MongoDB is client-server database. However, it is no problem to move/copy the DB-Files from one machine to another. But the service should be stopped.